# rosdep doesn't install dependencies

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Noetic ros_comm on Raspian Buster, on a raspberry pi 4b. I've activated my catkin workspace, downloaded the navigation package, and extracted the package to catkin_ws/src

From /catkin_ws/, I ran

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y

pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-angles]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-angles
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-geometry-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-tf2-geometry-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-dynamic-reconfigure]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-dynamic-reconfigure
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-geometry-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-geometry-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-nav-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-nav-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-ros]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-tf2-ros
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-tf2
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-sensor-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-sensor-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-visualization-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-visualization-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-sensor-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-tf2-sensor-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-laser-geometry]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-laser-geometry
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-map-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-map-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-diagnostic-updater]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-diagnostic-updater
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-tf2-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-move-base-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-move-base-msgs
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-actionlib]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-actionlib
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-angles] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-geometry-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-dynamic-reconfigure] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-geometry-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-nav-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-ros] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-sensor-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-visualization-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-sensor-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-laser-geometry] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-map-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-diagnostic-updater] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-tf2-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-move-base-msgs] failed
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-actionlib] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-angles]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-tf2-geometry-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-dynamic-reconfigure]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-geometry-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-nav-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-tf2-ros]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-tf2]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-sensor-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-visualization-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-tf2-sensor-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-laser-geometry]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-map-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-diagnostic-updater]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-tf2-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-move-base-msgs]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-noetic-actionlib]
```

Why won't rosdep successfully install my dependencies? Is this possible to fix?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368458/rosdep-doesn%27t-install-dependencies/) by [g-builds](https://answers.ros.org/users/66548/g-builds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-28**:
@g-builds if @tfoote's answer answered your question, then please click on the check mark (✓) next to the answer instead of closing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're running Rasbian Buster you're likely on an armhf build and noetic does not have packages built for buster on armhf http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation only amd64 and arm64.

You will either need to follow the compile from source instructions or use an Ubuntu based image for the Rasbperry Pi to use the binary packages for installation.

PS in the future please provide enough information to explain how you have setup your system. For example what installation instructions you followed, as well as what your apt sources are setup as and what the commands that you're running and previously have run to get into the current situation. My answer above is an informed guess based on knowleged about general systems and not much based on your description. If you want more help you will need to give more details.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1